# How to prepare UDP datagrams for sending to server

Tags: c, arrays, udp, datagram

I have to write a program which sends files from a UDP client to a UDP server.

I have no problems sending data over this kind of connection, but a different matter is taking care of our protocol specification. Maybe someone can help me to understand how to realize these steps correctly:

### Step 1:

Send first package: First Element of data array, `int` value for type specification.

After that the filename size (without path) as `unsigned short`.

After that the filename (without path) as C-string without NULL termination.

At least there should be the file length as `unsigned integer`.

*Both sizes should be sent in network byte order!*

All this information has to be in *one* single datagram. So actually I just have an `unsigned char` array which is sent by the client.

I thought I could assign anything to this one array, one after another. But don't think this works.

### Step 2:

Send second package: Type specification as `int` as first element. Then the data of the given file (I saved it as `unsigned char` array too). That's much easier because I just have information which is easy to put in my `unsigned char` array.

So, I think, there must be a way to build a generic method or something like that, that returns a datagram, so I can fill in all data types I want to have in this datagram and get my datagram ready to send, you know?

It would be nice if someone has an idea on how I can "prepare" a datagram in the right way - the most important thing for me is:

Which kind of type should my datagram array have? To send it with `sendTo()` it needs to be a `unsigned char` array, right?

Best greetings, and thanks a lot!

Comment: You should look into packages that do this, such as XDR.

Answer (score -2):

you can use a structs to map your informations for example:

```
struct Packet {
   unsigned short filnemanesize;
   char [MAX_LEN] filename;
   unsigned int   filesize;
   //etc.
}
```

You *can* send this struct directrly through the socket

```
send(mySocket, (void*) myStruct, sizeof(myStuct), 0);
```

**BUT** the compilers uising a different member packing, so it would happen that the server sees different data. (Its safe for exact the same plattform/compiler).

A common practice is, serializing your struct into a char array, here is a complete example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;


#define MAX_FILENAME_SIZE 10
typedef struct {
    int32_t type;
    uint16_t fileNameSize;
    uint32_t extraPadding; //just some manual padding (example)
    char fileName [MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];
    uint32_t fileSize;
} Packet;

const size_t PACKET_RAW_SIZE = sizeof(int32_t) + sizeof(uint16_t) + (MAX_FILENAME_SIZE * sizeof(char)) + sizeof(uint32_t);

size_t serialize(unsigned char * const dst, const Packet * src) {

    /*  Protocoll Specification:
        [Type:4Byte][fileNameSize:2Byte][fileName:nByte][fileSize:4Byte]
    */


    uint16_t offset = 0;

    //type
    memcpy(dst + offset, &src->type, sizeof(src->type));
    offset += sizeof(src->type);

    //fileNameSize
    memcpy(dst + offset, &src->fileNameSize, sizeof(src->fileNameSize));
    offset += sizeof(src->fileNameSize);

    //fileName
    memcpy(dst + offset, &src->fileName, ntohs(src->fileNameSize));
    offset += ntohs(src->fileNameSize);

    //fileSize
    memcpy(dst + offset, &src->fileSize, sizeof(src->fileSize));
    offset += sizeof(src->fileSize);

    return offset;
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned char buffer[PACKET_RAW_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < PACKET_RAW_SIZE; buffer[i++] = 0);  //nice visual effect, not nessasarry
    Packet myPacket;
    myPacket.type = htonl(0xAFFEAFFE);                  
    myPacket.fileNameSize = htons(4);                       //convert 4 to network byte order as required
    myPacket.fileSize = htonl(42);
    myPacket.fileName[0] = 'T';                         
    myPacket.fileName[1] = 'E';
    myPacket.fileName[2] = 'S';
    myPacket.fileName[3] = 'T';

    myPacket.extraPadding = 0xFFFFFFFF;                     // better visual effect

    cout << "struct Packet size: " << sizeof(Packet) << endl;
    cout << "PACKET_RAW_SIZE: " << PACKET_RAW_SIZE << endl;

    size_t bufferSize = serialize(&buffer[0], &myPacket);

    cout << "myPacket: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(myPacket); i++) {
        unsigned char * ptr = (unsigned char *) &myPacket;
        cout << std::showbase << std::hex << "Offset: " << i * sizeof(unsigned char) << "\t Value: " <<  (uint16_t)*(ptr + i) << "\t" << *(ptr + i) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "buffer: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        cout << std::showbase << std::hex << "Offset: " << i * sizeof(unsigned char) << "\t Value: " << (uint16_t)buffer[i] << "\t" << buffer[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

/* 
    Program-Output:

    struct Packet size : 28
    PACKET_RAW_SIZE : 20
    myPacket :
    Offset : 0        Value : 0xaf    »
    Offset : 0x1      Value : 0xfe    ■
    Offset : 0x2      Value : 0xaf    »
    Offset : 0x3      Value : 0xfe    ■
    Offset : 0x4      Value : 0
    Offset : 0x5      Value : 0x4     ♦ 
    Offset : 0x6      Value : 0x9a    Ü
    Offset : 0x7      Value : 0xf     ☼
    Offset : 0x8      Value : 0xff
    Offset : 0x9      Value : 0xff
    Offset : 0xa      Value : 0xff
    Offset : 0xb      Value : 0xff
    Offset : 0xc      Value : 0x54    T
    Offset : 0xd      Value : 0x45    E
    Offset : 0xe      Value : 0x53    S
    Offset : 0xf      Value : 0x54    T
    Offset : 0x10     Value : 0x52    R
    Offset : 0x11     Value : 0x17    ↨
    Offset : 0x12     Value : 0x9f    ƒ
    Offset : 0x13     Value : 0xf     ☼
    Offset : 0x14     Value : 0x1     ☺
    Offset : 0x15     Value : 0
    Offset : 0x16     Value : 0
    Offset : 0x17     Value : 0
    Offset : 0x18     Value : 0
    Offset : 0x19     Value : 0
    Offset : 0x1a     Value : 0
    Offset : 0x1b     Value : 0x2a *

    buffer :
    Offset : 0        Value : 0xaf    »     | <= type
    Offset : 0x1      Value : 0xfe    ■     |
    Offset : 0x2      Value : 0xaf    »     |   
    Offset : 0x3      Value : 0xfe    ■     |   
    Offset : 0x4      Value : 0                 | <= fileNameSize
    Offset : 0x5      Value : 0x4     ♦         | (network byte order)
    Offset : 0x6      Value : 0x54    T             |   <= fileName
    Offset : 0x7      Value : 0x45    E             |
    Offset : 0x8      Value : 0x53    S             |
    Offset : 0x9      Value : 0x54    T             |
    Offset : 0xa      Value : 0                         | <= fileSize 
    Offset : 0xb      Value : 0                         | (network byte order)
    Offset : 0xc      Value : 0                         |
    Offset : 0xd      Value : 0x2a                      |

    */
```

You can see, the buffer contains only the required data. And the mapping is as required in the spec. All manual and compiler padding is not inside the buffer.
htons/htonl are used for byte order conversions.

Even better is some kind of text serialization such as xml or json (imho)

Comment: I think almost all of this is bad advice. The OP is basically asking for how to do binary serialization, and this answer lists two bad ways (because they both rely on platform details) and then suggests not doing binary serialization. Binary serialization is fine, and the protocols most like the OP's proposal (for example, TFTP) use it.

Comment: It is safe for exactly the same platform, compiler, compiler version, compiler options, surrounding #pragmas, source code version, ... In other words, not.

Comment: @David Schwartz why solution 2 is bad?

Comment: Because it is identical to solution 1 except  for the extra bitwise copy step, which just wastes space. And it is certainly *not* a 'common practice'.

Comment: I thought in solution 2 are no problems with paddings bits, can you explain why solution 2 is identical to 1?

Comment: Rubbish. All you're doing is a bitwise copy, with `memcpy().` That doesn't remove any of those problems.

Comment: hmm before I read the edits, that looked to me, like exactly that what I needed.. 
Has anyone else, a better Idea then?

Comment: But building a struct *myPacket* like the first advice, is the right way yet?

Comment: @ansanders No. I don't understand how you can possibly think so, given the comments here. See my comment under your question.

Comment: @EJP In my example i'm doing memcpy for each member, not for the whole struct. You may missunderstood me?

Comment: @David Schwartz look at: myPacket.fileNameSize = htons(4); myPacket.fileSize = htonl(42);